# The Testimony And The Spirit Of Prophecy

Tags: revelation

In the Book Of Revelation Chapter 19 v 10 it says:

> At this I fell at his feet to worship him.  But he said to me "Do not do it!  I am a fellow servant with you and with your brothers who hold to the testimony of Jesus.  Worship God!  For the testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy.

What does it mean "The testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy"?

Comment: hello Bagpipes.  Can you edit your question to show what research have you done on this already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "The testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy" I believe the angel was saying that Jesus Christ is the theme of the Bible from beginning to end.  Accordingly, [every book in the Old Testament/Tanakh points to Jesus prophetically](http://www.jesusplusnothing.com/jesus66books.htm).

From Genesis to Malachi (or in the Tanakh, from Genesis to Chronicles) there is [written *testimony*](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%205:39&version=ESV), that bears witness to the centrality of Jesus in the grand arc of history. All of history, is bound up in the unfolding story of the redemption of humankind which was accomplished once and for all with the perfect life and the death, burial, and resurrection of Jesus Christ.

Our first parents disobeyed God and by extension took the entire human race with them in their rebellion (since "in Adam, all die"--1 Corinthians 15:22).

God, in the opening chapters of the book of beginnings (Genesis/*Bereishis*), in what is called the "Proto Evangelium," or the "first gospel," revealed the first prophetic word which gave humankind the first inkling as to what God's plan for the ages would entail.

Before we consider this prophetic word, we must consider the events leading up to its being given to our first parents:

> - Adam and Eve were created in the image and likeness of the invisible God, with Adam being created first and given the headship  of the created order of living things God had placed in the earth and in the air and the sea, and Eve being created second as both a fit helper and equal partner to the man.  God then commanded them to bear children and thus fill and subdue the entire earth and exercise dominion over all that is in the earth.
> - Adam forfeited his rulership (or delegated dominion, Genesis 1:27) over God's earthly creation by allowing his wife Eve to partake of the only fruit which God had expressly forbidden them to eat. Adam, who was with his wife at the time she was deceived by the tempter (Genesis 3:6) allowed her to eat the forbidden fruit and then ate it himself.
> - Adam and his wife, rather than admitting their disobedience to God, make excuses--what today we would call rationalizations, with Adam blaming Eve, and Eve blaming the serpent (3:12,13).
> - God said to the tempter, "And I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between your seed and her seed; He shall bruise you on the head, and you shall bruise Him on the heel" (3:15).

In other words, since Adam had failed to exercise dominion as God intended, God Himself would provide through the seed of the woman "the last Adam"--that is, the perfect God-Man, Jesus, who would wrest from Satan the dominion that Adam had forfeited to him through disobedience.  Jesus would thereby become to all humankind "a life-giving spirit" (see 1 Corinthians 15:45-49).

In so doing, Jesus' efforts to that end would result in the heel of His foot being bruised by the seed of the serpent, which comprised both the demonic spirits who joined Satan in his rebellion in heaven, as well as the unbelieving segment of humanity which chooses to follow Satan's leadership in his rebellion against God on Planet Earth.  Praise be to God, however, the very foot that was bruised at Golgotha (Calvary) would crush the poison-filled head of the serpent at the cross of Christ, thus delivering a death blow to Satan (reference).

By having lost his dominion as the "god of this world," Satan played right into God's hands, so that God, in a holy, righteous, and just way could restore to humanity all they had lost in the fall.  Before Jesus could become a life-giving spirit to each individual member of humankind, however, [each person would need first to repent, and second, to believe in the seed of the woman; that is, Jesus.](http://www.reformed.org/documents/wcf_with_proofs/)   As Paul reminds us in Galatians,

> "But when the fullness of the time came, God sent forth His Son, born of a woman, born under the Law, so that He might redeem those who were under the Law, that we might receive the adoption as sons" (4:4:5).

And as John tells us in the first chapter of his gospel,

> ". . . as many as received [Jesus], to them He gave the right to become children of God, even to those who believe in His name" (v.12).

In conclusion, I refer you to an [excellent chart](http://www.jesusplusnothing.com/jesus66books.htm) which lays out for us very nicely the ways in which the testimony of Jesus can be found in every book of the Bible.  Going through the chart from beginning to end will likely cement in your mind and heart how the rich tapestry of scripture, though comprising many skeins, has one particularly beautiful skein the color of blood.

That skein had its beginning in Genesis 3:21 where God clothed His erring creatures in the Garden of Eden with the skins of animals whose blood had been shed.  It has its ending in the Revelation of Jesus Christ where we read that

> "[Jesus] is clothed with a robe dipped in blood, and His name is called 'The Word of God'" (19:13).

The prophetic word in Genesis 3:15 presaged the blood of the Lamb, who through His death bore our sins in His own body on the tree (1 Peter 2:24), and that word was fulfilled to the letter by the *Logos*, the living Word of God, who is our Lord and Savior, Jesus Christ.

Truly, the testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy, and each book in the Bible points to Him! See, for example, Psalm 22 and Isaiah 53. For "new covenant" references, see Luke 24:25-27, and 44-48; John 5:39; and Acts 8:26-38, reproduced below, respectively:

> "[Jesus] said to them, 'How foolish you are, and how slow of heart to believe all that the prophets have spoken! Did not the Christ have to suffer these things and then enter His glory?' And beginning with Moses and all the Prophets, he explained to them what was said in all the Scriptures concerning Himself."
>
> "'You [Jewish leaders] diligently study the Scriptures because you think that by them you possess eternal life. These are the Scriptures that testify about me, yet you refuse to come to me to have life.'"
>
> "Then Philip began with that very passage of Scripture [i.e., Isaiah 53:7.8] and told him [viz., the Ethiopian eunuch] the good news about Jesus."

Comment: Excellent link to seeing prophecies about Jesus/the Messiah in all the books of the Bible.

Comment: @Lesley: Thanks. I enjoyed it myself. I'd give everything I possess to have been a part of that conversation on the way to Emmaus, as found in Luke 24!

Comment: Just curious, but isn't being a "liberal conservative" a contradiction in terms? I know we're not allowed to have those sorts of discussions in comments, but can you point me to a link that might explain what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Legal testimony is part of a pattern which begins in Genesis 2-3. The Adam hears from God and is given promises. When that Word is challenged, he is to humble himself under the Law (a priestly act) and then act upon it (a kingly act of judgment upon the deceiver). The third step is a prophetic act, a legal testimony against the liar.

We see this exact process in Philippians 2 concerning Jesus. He humbled Himself under the Law (priesthood) and was exalted by God (kingdom). He sent His Spirit that the Church might testify concerning the crushing of the serpent (prophecy). This testimony is a legal witness against the "murderer from the beginning." The story of Abel's murder follows the same pattern, with Abel's blood crying from the ground as a legal witness against Cain, who had failed to "rule over" the evil one.

So the book of Revelation, like the rest of the apostolic Scriptures, is a legal witness against those who rejected (and blasphemed) the Spirit at Pentecost. It resulted in the destruction of the Temple and the final calling down of the Mosaic curses upon a disobedient Israel. Prophecy is always a legal witness, a "Trumpets" warning that judgment is impending. Thus Jesus warns that He is coming soon. And He did. The apostolic Church put a stop to the lies of Herodian worship which denied that Jesus, a better Abel, had come in the flesh. Their lies were apparent when the testimonies of their "legal witnesses" against Jesus did not corroborate (Mark 14:56), breaking the Law of Moses (Exodus 20:16).

*You are of your father the devil, and your will is to do your father's desires. He was a murderer from the beginning, and has nothing to do with the truth, because there is no truth in him. When he lies, he speaks out of his own character, for he is a liar and the father of lies*. (John 8:44)

Comment: @ Mike Bull, So what is the testimony of Jesus, Are you saying it is all of his prophecies?

Comment: @user2572 It is the witness of his resurrection, a legal witness that the law has been satisfied and sin atoned for. But this witness began with the apostolic witness which brought about the judgment upon those who stuck with the Old Covenant, and their temple, which is one big support for a preteristic interpretation of the New Testament.

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Question Restatement:

What does it mean "The testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy"?

---

## 2. The Text should be Taken Literally - According to the Plain Meaning:

The "breath /spirit / life / purpose" of prophecy is to faithfully represent who Jesus is, and even the Father.

**For example:** God corrected Job / his friends for not speaking rightly about him.

Every Prophet - in all of Scripture - was fulfilling a role of being a "Representative" of God, (or Jesus).

***In other words, a false-prophet would be someone representing their own interests, or other peoples'.***

> **NASB, Jeremiah 14:14** - Then the Lord said to me, “The prophets are prophesying falsehood in My name. ***I have neither sent them nor commanded them*** nor spoken to them; they are prophesying to you a false vision, divination, futility and the deception of their own minds.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my spirit picked it: When you testify about Jesus even in the midst of trials and tribulation you are actually prophesying a change from that situation. When you testify that Jesus is the healer to are declaring that Jesus is healing you! In any situation testifying about Jesus prophetically acknowledges what the WORD of God says about that situation in your life and when you believe the word and you speak it then you shall have what the word says.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  If you haven't done so already, check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour).  In particular, be sure to read the section on what constitutes a good answer and revise your post to either cite references that back your position or to more thoroughly explain how you get this interpretation from the text itself.  Please note that "showing your work" is [required](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/735/what-kind-of-site-do-we-ultimately-want-to-have/777#777) on this Stack Exchange.